# How to prevent javascript Stack Overflow on a jQuery droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, stack-overflow

Here's what I am doing:
I have an accordion from which I need to be able to drag and drop a li element in an editable div and upon the drop I need to open a dialog box which has some additional options,which upon selection need to be appended to the original li element.

This is what the script looks like:

```
jQuery("#formula").droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-default",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
            drop: function (event, ui) 
            {

            /* Popup logic */
                symbolicKey = ui.draggable.attr('title');
                symbolicId = ui.draggable.attr('id');
                var res = symbolicId.split(".");
                if(res[0] == "customIndex")
                {
                    jQuery("#periodOnly").dialog("open");
                }
                else
                {
                    jQuery(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
                    jQuery("<span class='vt' id=" + symbolicId + " contenteditable=false></span>").text("[" + symbolicKey + "]").appendTo(this);
                }



            }
        });
jQuery("#periodOnly").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function() 
                {
                    var period = $('select[property="customPeriod"]').val();
                    symbolicId = symbolicId + "."+period;
                    symbolicKey = symbolicKey + "."+period;
                    jQuery("#formula").find(".placeholder").remove();
                    jQuery("<span class='vt' id=" + symbolicId + " contenteditable=false></span>").text("[" + symbolicKey + "]").appendTo("#formula");
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
              },
              close: function() {
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              }
        });
```

From my understanding, its these two functions which are calling each other recursively and thereby causing a stack overflow however I cant seem to find any alternative to solving the problem i.e removing the recursion.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: At first I thought maybe you were checking to see if you should open the popup before the drop, but you look to be handling that right. Still looking. Are you sure it's coming from these two calls?

Comment: Its the only thing that I could think of :| The scenario is like this,  The accordion contains different groups and for a certain li element which is inside the Custom Index group I have to generate a popup which  contains a selectbox with values current and last, the selection needs to be appended to the draggable element. For ex. Accordion has **customIndex1** which we drag on to the droppable div and from the popup we select **current** then inside the droppable div I need **customIndex1.current**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the `close` method for the dialog box which was causing the recursion! Silly on my part!